# Logitech Unifying Receiver causes mouse pointer freeze Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, mouse, logitech, mouse-pointer

I have used Logitech Unifying Receivers on 2 laptops for several years. Until a few weeks ago they have worked fine. Since then both computers exhibit the same behaviour when the Receiver is plugged in: The mouse pointer freezes in the top left corner of the display and the touchpad won't work right either. You can see that the touchpad moves the cursor very briefly but it snaps right back to the corner.

Removing the Receiver(s) allows the touchpad to work.

Both machines are running Ubuntu 22.04.

The only thing different that comes to mind is that I have been using a Western Digital Passport drive (USB) but since the troubles I haven't been plugging it in. No change.

Apologies because I don't know what other diagnostics to attach.

Comment: Have you tried connecting another mouse to the receiver? Or to use another receiver?

Comment: I don't have a wired mouse but swapping the Receivers gives the same behaviour.